# Make balconys in organic shape skyscraper

Tags: modifiers

**Hi, as you can see on my sketch, i want to design that skyscraper's balconys, as you can see in the sketch each balcony goes outside of the main shape. I manage to model the main shape of the building and what i was trying to do now is to model only one balcony ( with railing and small details ) and then duplicate many times and finally putting all of them it on that main shape. But i don't know how to do it. As you can see in 3D screenshot i managed to do stripes around the shape with Shrinkwrap,add a solidify and that's it. Nothing fancy. If i want to make a unique balcony with many details and then duplicate it and apply all of them to the shape i don't know how to do it. Any help or advice? I attached sketch, 3d screenshot and the 3D file i cannot upload it. But like i said, is basically putting many balconys into a organic shape.

THANKS**

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCsD5.jpg)
[image]

Comment: I would take the stripes as mesh lines, convert them to a curve and make the railing and small details by arraying along the curves and using a profile along the curve for the shape of the balcony.

Comment: Thanks it worked!